# How to get the certain cell of previous row arraylist java

Tags: java, apache-poi

I have arraylist like this

```
[111, 222, 333, 444, 555, 666, , ]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, , ]
[11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, , ]
[a, s, d, f, g, h, , ]
```

I want to check when it found 'h', it will check for the previous row of the first cell whether it equal to '11'

So far, I have done this

```
DataFormatter formatter = new DataFormatter();

        String val = null;

        for (int rowNum = 0; rowNum < sheet.getLastRowNum() + 1; rowNum++) {
            Row r = sheet.getRow(rowNum);

            ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<String>();

            for (int i = 0; i <= r.getLastCellNum() + 1; i++) {
                Cell cell = r.getCell(i);
                val = formatter.formatCellValue(cell);
                al.add(val);
            }

for (int t = 0; t < al.size(); t++) {

    if (al.get(t).equals("h") && al.get(t + 1).equals("") && al.get(t + 2).equals("")) {

                    if (al.get(rowNum - 1) != null) {

                        if (al.get(rowNum - 1).contains("11")) {
                            System.out.println("valid");
                            continue;
                        } else {
                            System.out.println("invalid");
                            continue;
                        }
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("empty cell not exist ");
                        continue;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

output : `invalid`

BUT
when I change to this :

```
for (int t = 0; t < al.size(); t++) {

    if (al.get(t).equals("16") && al.get(t + 1).equals("") && al.get(t + 2).equals("")) {

            if (al.get(rowNum - 1) != null) {

                        if (al.get(rowNum - 1).contains("1")) {
                            System.out.println("valid");
                            continue;
                        } else {
                            System.out.println("invalid");
                            continue;
                        }
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("empty cell not exist ");
                        continue;
                    }
                }
            }
```

output : `valid` and same result if I change the '1' to '2' too, but not 3,4,5,6

can someone explain to me?

**UPDATE**

As suggested, the problem was my arraylist. Hence now, I change it to this but I got stuck. Is it appropriate to update here or should I ask new question?

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> mainArrayList = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();

        ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<String>();

        for (int rowNum = 0; rowNum < sheet.getLastRowNum() + 1; rowNum++) {
            Row r = sheet.getRow(rowNum);

            String val = null;
            for (int i = 0; i < r.getLastCellNum() + 1; i++) {
                Cell cell = r.getCell(i);
                val = formatter.formatCellValue(cell);
            }

            al.add(val);
            mainArrayList.add(al);
            System.out.println(mainArrayList);
        }
```

output:

```
[[]]
[[, ], [, ]]
[[, , ], [, , ], [, , ]]
[[, , , ], [, , , ], [, , , ], [, , , ]]
```

I believe because I declare my `String val = null;`.

**I HAVE ASK NEW QUESTION REGARDING THE ArrayList>**

[How to store data from excel to ArrayList>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53095040/how-to-store-data-from-excel-to-arraylistarrayliststring)

**FULL ANSWER**

Thank you to our friend, Bejond for helping me out to solve this problem, here is the full code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File("xx"));
        XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(file);
        XSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);

        DataFormatter formatter = new DataFormatter();

        ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> mainArrayList = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();

        ArrayList<String> al = null;

        for (int rowNum = 0; rowNum < sheet.getLastRowNum() + 1; rowNum++) {
            al = new ArrayList<String>();

            String val = null;

            Row r = sheet.getRow(rowNum);

            for (int m = 0; m <= r.getLastCellNum() + 1; m++) {
                Cell cell = r.getCell(m);
                val = formatter.formatCellValue(cell);
                al.add(val);
            }
            mainArrayList.add(al);
        }

        for (int t = 0; t < mainArrayList.size(); t++) {
            ArrayList<String> row = mainArrayList.get(t);

            for (int i = 0; i < row.size(); i++) {

                if (row.get(i).equals("13") && row.get(i - 1).equals("12")) {
                    // your code

                    ArrayList tempRow = mainArrayList.get(t - 1);

                    if (tempRow.size() > 0) {

                        if (tempRow.get(2).equals("3")) {
                            System.out.println("FOUND");
                            break;
                        }else {
                            System.out.print("nope");
                            continue;
                        }

                    } else {
                        System.out.print("false");
                        continue;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    } catch (

    Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

In this code, if you compare with the previous original code, I did some change as advised to ArrayList> mainArrayList = new ArrayList>(); .

and then for the checking, I check when it found the value "13" and the previous index is equal to "12" , it will go to the previous row to check at index 2 whether the value "3" is exist or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First your data structure is not good. I suggest you create a `ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>` to save your data. Put each row into one ArrayList, then add the ArrayList to main ArrayList. Now the data structure is just the same as you mentioned above. Or you can choose dyadic array, like `String[][] arr = new String[10][];`.

You put the line `ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<String>();` in `for loop`, means in each loop, you create a new ArrayList `al`, so the data in `al` is totally empty in each loop. If you want `al` keep all data, you need to move `ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<String>();` out of loop.

For your code, when `(al.get(t).equals("h") && al.get(t + 1).equals("") && al.get(t + 2).equals(""))` is true, rowNum is 3, al is `[a, s, d, f, g, h, , ]`, al.get(rowNum - 1) is "d".

When `(al.get(t).equals("16") && al.get(t + 1).equals("") && al.get(t + 2).equals(""))` is true, rowNum is 2, al is `[11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, , ]`, al.get(rowNum -1) is "12".

Besides, you shouldn't use `al.get(rowNum - 1).contains("11")`, you should use `al.get(rowNum - 1).equals("11")` instead.

=================

```
for (int t = 0; t < mainArrayList.size(); t++) {
    ArrayList<String> row = mainArrayList.get(t);
    for (int i = 0; i < row.size(); i++) {
        if (row.get(i).equals("h") {
          // your code
        }
    }
}
```

`row` is the each row of your sheet. You need to loop each row to check each of String equals with "h".

Comment: can u help me again? see my latest post updates @Bejond

Comment: Now you create mainArrayList, you need to put `al` in `for loop`. Because now `al` needs to be new in each loop.

Comment: may I know which 'for' ? I am sorry, I am still sucks at this looping. @Bejond

Comment: I've answered in the new question

Comment: @Bojand refering to my code for checking the value of String, now I have to loop like this `for (int t = 0; t < mainArrayList.size(); t++) {` inside the `rowNum` right?

Comment: Yes it is. mainArrayList.get(t) is a row of your sheet

Comment: and as for individual checking like this `if (al.get(t).equals("h")) {` ?

Comment: according to your new update, what if I want to check the next index of the current cell? lets say I want to to know t+1?

Comment: I change `for each loop` to `for(;;)` now. You can get the index by `t` or `i`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182911/discussion-between-sharky-and-bejond).